# Python/Django user detail view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests

I have problem with Django Rest, about user edit and detail.

So this is the code

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdminOrReadOnly]
    throttle_scope = 'edit_user'
```

and view.py is like

```
path('<slug:username>/edit/', UserUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='user-update'),
```

What I need to do is to delete this `<slug:username>` and set it to be only /edit so when I'm calling for example

> http://localhost:8000/api/user/edit/

I will receive current info about my account in API and can change it if I want.
I know this is put method, so is it possible to return current informations in json format about my account?

Comment: i dont know what you want. Do you want return data of `user` after call put `user/edit` , like data after updated ?

Answer (score 0):

You need make little modification to your view.

So it will look like this:

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = None
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdminOrReadOnly]
    throttle_scope = 'edit_user'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

and you can use the view for the endpoint : http://localhost:8000/api/user/edit/

Comment: Now is giving that /user/edit/ is not found. I changed in urls.py like path('edit/', UserUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='user-update'), but still nothing.

Comment: @RadeIlijev that's configuration issue.  you mentioned 'api/user/edit' .so perhaps api is missing ?